# jquery validator method not called when backspace or delete is pressed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Please help...

I'm having trouble to find out why my jquery valitdator method is not fired when a delete or backspace key is pressed. Below is my code and please provide your valuable suggestions to fix this..

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkBlankContactNos", function (value, element) {

    ...............

    // some business logic to validate if the textbox is null or not null..

    ...........
    ...........

    }, "Required. Please enter a number");
```

And added a class rule..

```
    jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
            planningFieldContactNo:{
               required: false,
               digits: false,
               contactNoRegex: true,
               checkDuplicateContactNos: true,
               checkBlankContactNos: true
            }

    });
```

Below I validate before submitting the form -

```
$("#customer").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {  
        name: { 
            required: true,
            customerNameRegex: true,
            remote: {
                url: "${checkCustomerNameUrl}",
                    type:"get",
                data: {
                  custid: function() {
                    return $("#customerId").val();
                  }
                }  
              }
        }
    }, 
    messages: {
        name:
            {
                required:  "Please specify a customer name",
                customerNameRegex: "Invalid characters. Allowed characters include a-z A-Z 0-9 and [] () & space . _ -",
                remote: "Customer name already exists"
            }
    },
    submitHandler: function() {

    },
    success: function(label) {
    },
    invalidHandler: function(e,validator) {

    },
    onkeyup: false,
    //onfocusout: true,
    //onclick: false,
    onsubmit: false
});
```

Please advice..

Thanks, Sirish.

Comment: As far as I know methods are only fired on blur and submit events.

Comment: Thank you @Philippe. Well, I think we can override this using -onclick: true or onkeyup:true in the validate method, but when I tried  I see error in firebug. Below is the error text from console - TypeError: validator.settings[eventType].call is not a function
 

validator.settings[eventType].call(validator, this[0], event);

Comment: That's because `onkeyup` does not accept true as its value. It only accepts `false` which is the default value and indicates the plugin that it should not validate the rules on keyUp events or a function that you is mandatory for the developer to implement.

Comment: Thanks again for the detail. I came to know about this just a few mins back and when I googled I think the found the root cause and a fix to this. What you said was right and in order to enable the onKeyUp thing, I need to override it with the element - onkeyup: function(element) {$(element).valid()},                                that did the trick. I will test this and post my updates. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to help. I would suggest you to edit your question and remove the jquery-validation-engine because it's another plugin not related to jquery validate.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your time and help. Much appreciated. And btw, I tested the fix and its working as expected. Will post my answer shortly.

Comment: **Quote @Philippe:** _"As far as I know methods are only fired on blur and submit events."_  ~  **false**... by default, all methods are also fired on every key up.

Comment: **Quote @Philippe:**  _"That's because onkeyup does not accept true as its value. It only accepts false which is the default value"_  ~ This is only a half-truth.  `false` is **not** the default value.  While you cannot set it to `true`, that's only because `onkeyup` is already the default behavior of the plugin.

Comment: @Philippe, I suggest that you read the documentation regarding `onkeyup` before spreading more misinformation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it.. I have changed

```
 onkeyup:true,
```

to

```
 onkeyup: function(element) {$(element).valid()},
```

That did the trick and resolved my issue.

Many Thanks,
Sirish.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote Title:**  *"jQuery Validator method not called when backspace or delete is pressed"*

That's because you've disabled the key-up events with this...

```
onkeyup: false,
```

**The default behavior is `onkeyup` so you simply need to remove that line entirely**.

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/),

> **onkeyup**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>  Validate elements on keyup. As long as the field is not marked as invalid, nothing happens.
>   Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key up event. Set to `false`
>   to disable. Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run
>   validation.
>
> **A boolean `true` is not a valid value.**

In other words...

- if you want validation to occur on every keystroke, you leave out the `onkeyup` option. (default)
- if you want to disable validation on every keystroke, set `onkeyup` to `false`.
- if you need to run a custom callback function on every keystroke, set `onkeyup` to your over-riding function.